# Equation of a straight line in the form $ax+by+c=0$

Tags: geometry

The question:

"Find, in each case, the equation of the straight line with gradient $m$ which passes through the point $p$. Give your answer in the form $ax+by+c=0$, where $a,b,c$ are integers."

a) $m=-4$,  $P(-1,8)$

Would the correct answer be $y+4x+4=0$? And if not could you show your working so that I can see where I went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Generally, you are expected to provide your own work so that others can show you where you went wrong. Next time, users might not be so friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your notation: the wanted line is

$$y-8=(-4)(x+1)=-4x-4\implies y+4x-4=0$$

So you got it almost alright.

Comment: thank you. what about if the value for m was 1/2 and the point(6,1)?  for this i received the answer y-1/2x-2=0 is this correct ?

Comment: For that I get $\;y-\frac12x\color{red}+2=0\;$ . You need to go over this stuff only once again since you seem to be missing something about signs...

Comment: Thank you so much. But it says Give your answer in the form ax+by+c=0, where a,b,c are integers. Is 1/2  considered an integer ?

Comment: @Dan Nop, it isn't...but then you can multiply the whole equation by $\;2\; $ :$$2\left(y-\frac12x+2=0\right)\implies 2y-x+4=0$$

Comment: would you always multiply by 2 when this occurs ? or by different numbers to get whole integers ? for example y-2/5x-6.2=0 ? thanks.

Comment: Well, you will multiply by the minimal common multiple of all the denominators, of course. In your last example, that number is 5 ( since $\;6.2=\frac{31}5\;$) , and if you had $$\frac13y+x-\frac14=0$$ then you'd have to multiply by $\;12\;$ , and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is almost correct. For these type of questions there are three steps that can be taken in order to get the solution and check whether its correct:

1) Given m and the coordinates of the point $(x,y)$ on the line $y=mx+c$, plug in the value of $m$ and $(x,y)$ inside the equation $y=mx+c$,(note that if you rearrange this equation you'll get the equation of the form $ax+by+C=0$, where $b=1,a=-m$ and $C=-c$ ).

2) Once you have $c$ you can substitute the values of $m$ and $c$ back to the equation  $y=mx+c$. Then by bringing all the variables on the L.H.S you can get the form $ax+by+C=0$.

3) Check that you've got the correct equation by plugging in the values for $(x,y)$ inside the equation obtained in step 2) and see if it equates to zero. If it doesn't then something went wrong in step 1 or 2.

If you plug in $(-1,4)$ in $y+4x+4$, you don't get zero. Instead you get $y+4x+4=4$. Check the value of $C$ that you calculated.